# Why did the status of my paper change from "awaiting reviewer scores" back to "under review"?

Tags: peer-review, journals, paper-submission

I submitted a paper to a journal that uses the ScholarOne submission system. The manuscript status has changed from "awaiting reviewer scores" back to "under review".

What does this change mean? Does it mean that one of the selected reviewers has declined the invitation? Is it a bad sign?

Comment: Thank you! But in the journal i submitted to, under review means AE is examining the paper as the first stage, while "awaiting reviewer scores" means it's actually out for review. So I just wonder why it was returned to the AE again...

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that a reviewer who previously agreed to review the paper has changed his mind, therefore the paper went back to the AE who will now find a new reviewer.

But the truth is we do not really know (and should probably not care). Only the journal knows the reason for the status change and they will contact you when the reviews are in.